# Error generating .ipa: "remove ... directory not empty"

Tags: xcode, macos, ipa

I'm trying to generate an .ipa file from xcode, version 10.
Certainly I am using the option "Archive" under "Product" menu option, towards a Generic iOS Device.

The problem comes when it starts building it. The following error appears:

[image]

I have tried cleaning the build folder, removing the folder mentioned in the error (it gets regenerated after I press Archive), I also tried deleting DerivedData folder, changing it's destination...

What am I doing wrong? How would I go to generate an .ipa file?

I have read a lot of questions here in SO about this but none of them worked for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up being able to generate the .ipa with the legacy build system.